# Custom templates Xcode to C++ project

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I'm going to edit my question.
    When I want to developer in C++, I go to:
    Xcode => New Project => macOS => Command Line Tools => File C++.
    When I edit the main.cpp, the content is to defect (with int main(int argc, const char * argv[])....//More code..).

I create a new templates here (To right of Command Line Tools):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zq9V.png)

```
Then, I need to create a new project here:

 Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project_Templates/name_group = Applications(for_example)/nametemplate.xctemplate / 

Here there are several files:

-main.cpp (my template basic c++)
-TemplateIcon.icns (icon of 128 px)
-TemplateInfo.plist : file configured

But this file I don´t know how modify :(
I´ve tryied to put file templateInfo.plist of this directory: Applications/Xcode.app/Content Packets/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates / File Templates / C++....

But Xcode don´t recognize, I know that problem is in TemplateInfo.plist but I don´t know how I can modify :(

Now, Do I explained me better?

Thank you!!
```

Comment: It is hard to understand the specifics of what you are asking. What is a defect template? Update your question with what you want to achieve and what the problem is with the Xcode templates. All anyone can tell right now is you have a problem with something in the C++ file Xcode creates. But they cannot tell the specific problem. That is why you need to update your question.

Comment: Now I´ve modified the content of post. Thanks.